# Typescript modify type based on generic

Tags: typescript, generics, overloading

### Question

Is there a way for the generic of a type to modify the type itself?
Can it be done without creating two functions?
This is not about js functionality, only about getting the types to match.

### Example

When I call a function with the generic `HTMLInputElement`, I would like the return type to be  `Array<HTMLInputElement>`.
When I call it with `HTMLSelectElement` it should be `Array<HTMLSelectElement>`.
But, when I call it with `never` or don't supply a generic, it should be `string`.

Minified example, that doesn't work since the return type is always `Array<T> | string` (T has the right value though):

```
type InteractiveElement = HTMLInputElement | HTMLSelectElement;

function getValue<T extends InteractiveElement = never>(): Array<T> | string {
  return null as unknown as Array<T> | string; // 
}

const inputValue = getValue<HTMLInputElement>(); // should be ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>
const selectValue = getValue<HTMLSelectElement>(); // should be ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>
const emptyValue = getValue(); // should be string
```

Comment: What `ChangeEvent` type are you using? The DOM's `change` event just uses `Event`. Are you using React or similar?

Comment: Use overloads: https://tsplay.dev/N5QaZN

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes I'm using react, I forgot to remove it, I replaced it with `Array` since the root type isn't relevant.

Comment: @nickzoum - Yeah, just tidy if we know what it is. `Array` works. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this either by [overloading](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) `getValue()` so the non-[generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) call signature is first:

```
function getValue(): string;
function getValue<T extends InteractiveElement>(): Array<T>;
function getValue() {
    return null!
}

const inputValue = getValue<HTMLInputElement>(); // Array<HTMLInputElement>
const selectValue = getValue<HTMLSelectElement>(); // Array<HTMLSelectElement>
const emptyValue = getValue(); // string
```

Or you can make the function return a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) which checks if `T` is `never` (which requires that the conditional type not be [distributive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types), hence the wrapping with `[`+`]`) and returns `string` if so, or `Array<T>` if not:

```
function getValue<T extends InteractiveElement = never>():
    [T] extends [never] ? string : Array<T> {
    return null!
}

const inputValue = getValue<HTMLInputElement>(); // Array<HTMLInputElement>
const selectValue = getValue<HTMLSelectElement>(); // Array<HTMLSelectElement>
const emptyValue = getValue(); // string
```

Either way, this example cannot be properly implemented since there are no actual function parameters for the JavaScript to act upon.  But since you said it was "minified" maybe it doesn't matter.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdsCAnAhgY2ASwG4QKIA2EAthAlALxQASAKgLIAy8YArsISWcFAD40NGAZQhEMnUggDcAKDlwUpAM5h00AMIB7OABNMWbSgJQA3nKgWoAM1ZwMmbVADmEYADUjrCAB5aUCAAeiLpKsAjI6Fi4EtyUUHAQuEgAfAAUAJQAXDKWuVAA2rQAuv5BZDqh+QlJJQD8UErASJhwTlCZUACCSKggvsmmOXkWSK6sSHDxrAQEAIRDFgC+5pZo2o1QLWzuntBULjsEXt50TCzsMQhp6VJQAPR3XT0ofafMcNuXwMkLUGtwGyUoggGA8Rz2zlcYOObxEYg4REk3wytweT16J0EcJBCK4V1+-w2JDAoGhEIOZJR90ejWarTkMmWMgUylUaGgAHkkgRNCgdINfjY7AZJhTdhkOrSWk5ZLkhfZHGLwb5SsEKmFEKh7NFEdxrh1uhjaMlZZZ5SLIYcvBlBsMRmMJlMZvNckzcoSeFt2GS4kqYYJzrikddUY9DS9MWcPhddfj3eseED4T79lDdpHhMDxLHkTdqeiI7Cs0G9QSE-5iCSQCnLZS82ipfS5IsgA)

Comment: `[T] extends [never]` -- I'll have to try to remember that. :-)

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. I guess I'll have to read up a bit on conditional types.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above answer here is an example using `undefined` type instead of `never`. It also uses conditional types  what seems to be the most suitable approach here.

```
type InteractiveElement = HTMLInputElement | HTMLSelectElement;
type EventByValue<T> = T extends undefined ? string : ChangeEvent<T> 

function getValue<T extends InteractiveElement | undefined = undefined>(): EventByValue<T> {
  return null as any
}

const inputValue = getValue<HTMLInputElement>(); //  ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>
const selectValue = getValue<HTMLSelectElement>(); // ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>
const emptyValue = getValue(); // string
```